# Upload a file with python using httplib

Tags: python, httplib

```
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("www.encodable.com/uploaddemo/")
conn.request("POST", path, chunk, headers)
```

Above is the site "www.encodable.com/uploaddemo/" where I want to upload an image.

I am better versed in `php` so I am unable to understand the meaning of path and headers here. In the code above, `chunk` is an object consisting of my image file. 
The following code produces an error as I was trying to implement without any knowledge of headers and path.

```
import httplib

def upload_image_to_url():

    filename = '//home//harshit//Desktop//h1.jpg'
    f = open(filename, "rb")
    chunk = f.read()
    f.close()

    headers = {
        "Content−type": "application/octet−stream",
        "Accept": "text/plain"
    }

    conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("www.encodable.com/uploaddemo/")
    conn.request("POST", "/uploaddemo/files/", chunk)

    response = conn.getresponse()
    remote_file = response.read()
    conn.close()
    print remote_file

upload_image_to_url()
```

Answer (score 6):

Currently, you aren't using the headers you've declared earlier in the code.  You should provide them as the fourth argument to `conn.request`:

```
conn.request("POST", "/uploaddemo/files/", chunk, headers)
```

Also, side note: you can pass `open("h1.jpg", "rb")` directly into `conn.request` without reading it fully into `chunk` first.  `conn.request` accepts file-like objects and it will be more efficient to stream the file a little at a time:

```
conn.request("POST", "/uploaddemo/files/", open("h1.jpg", "rb"), headers)
```

Comment: That is what I am trying to ask I don't know how to put headers

Comment: And I'm telling you that you properly made the `headers` dictionary, but you have to pass it to your `conn.request` function in order for it to do anything.