# Use httplib to post a file

Tags: python, httplib

How to use **httplib** to post a file as binary? 
Can I not use other module?
It failed for me. Please see the Image.

[image]

In PHP has `Print_r($_Files)` so that I can see the reason.

Thanks

Comment: Please post the code that caused this error, also please dont post code or errors as images. You should paste the actual text into the question. As for using `httplib`, it will be possible, but there are higher level libraries that will make it easier, see [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) module docs.

Comment: @PaulRooney  thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upload a file with python using httplib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079562/upload-a-file-with-python-using-httplib)

Comment: You can even try `requests` - http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file

Comment: related: [Using MultipartPostHandler to POST form-data with Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/680305/4279)